# How to get the value of ~ in an mvc view?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need to get the absolute path of the root in an asp.net mvc view

I guess one way would be to do `Url.Action("Index","Home")` and will get 
http://localhost/myapp

anybody knows the right way ?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. The root of the OS or the root of your URLs? The root of the OS can be accessed in your controller method, in the usual way. The root of your URLs is entirely dependent on your routing strategy.

Comment: I don't think there really is a "root" in MVC the way there is in ASP.NET forms. "Root" refers to some sort of document/resource heirarchy, whereas MVC is based solely on routing.

Comment: @Robert Harvey my goal is to make a link to a web-forms aspx so I will use it for root + Report.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Url.Content()` will give you that. It's intended to allow you to get the path for static files, such as

```
<img src='<%: Url.Content("~/images/logo.gif") %>' />
```

Calling `Url.Content("~")` will return `/myapp/`, or just `/` if your application isn't in a virtual directory.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use

```
string urlBase = Request.Url.GetLeftPart( UriPartial.Authority ) + Request.ApplicationPath;
```